# Using a loaded String in a case statment

Tags: java, string, enums, switch-statement, loading

I have a problem when I am loading a String with :

```
    public  void loadGameDataFromFile() {   
    try 
    {
        FileInputStream saveFile = new FileInputStream("SaveObj.sav");  
    ObjectInputStream objectStream = new ObjectInputStream(saveFile);   
     place = (String) objectStream.readObject(); // place is a string //defined at the start of my class
    objectStream.close();
    saveFile.close();
    System.out.println(place);
    }catch(Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }

}
```

After loading the String like this i try to use a case with it and there shows up the problem.It seems to me that it doesn't compares them like it should.

That is the code of the switch statment:

```
 public enum Places
    {
    Anfang,
    Strand,
    Wald, Waldex, Berg, Höhle, Höhlet, Haus1, Haus2, Haus3, Haus4, Strandex,        Höhlett, Kampf, Lichtung, Wald2, Fuß, Bergm, Spitze, Keller, Strand2, Strandx2, Gespräch,Höhlettt   //this are the Strings which my String "place" can be...
    }

public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent evt)
  {

       Places replace = Places.valueOf(place);
       switch(replace)
        {
        case Anfang: //do my stuff 
         break;
        case Strand: //do my stuff 
         break;
        case Wald: //do my stuff
         break;
        }
   }
```

This problem only appears when I use the String after it was loaded.When I start it without loading the String it just works fine.

When I remove the enum and use just my String in the switch statment it has the same problem that it doesnt seem to understand that the String equals one of the cases.

Update:
The problem still exists and I could change my case to if else but this would be retreating from solving the problem.

Comment: It's really hard to read this code because it doesn't use standard Java conventions: variables should start with a lowercase letter, and ideally, enum constants should be all-caps.  Is `Place` intended to be a class?  A variable?  What is its type?

Comment: what exactly is the problem? what is it expected to do and what is it actually doing?

Comment: You can see in the loading that Place is my String....and the conventions are thing which often ignore...for this a sorry.

Comment: switch is there for showing decided by the String Place different text, but after i loaded the string it doesnt works anymore...I already tried to fix it with the enum, but it has still the same problem.

Comment: Is the `String` in the correct case? e.g. Anfang rather than anfang? Also, check right before the `switch` statement what the value of places is.

Comment: yeah it has the right String. That is the problem i have with it.

Answer (score -1):

Whats the problem with this method:

```
public  String loadGameDataFromFile() {   
try 
{
    FileInputStream saveFile = new FileInputStream("SaveObj.sav");  
ObjectInputStream objectStream = new ObjectInputStream(saveFile);   
String place = (String) objectStream.readObject();
objectStream.close();
saveFile.close();
return place; // return the string
}catch(Exception e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    return "";
    }
}
public void main(String arg[]){
    String place = loadGameDataFromFile();
    // instead of unnecessary switch case...
    if(place.equals("something")){
    }else if(place.equals("something else")){
    ...
    }else if(...){
    ...
    }
}
```

Another method for Java SE 7:

```
    String string = loadGameDataFromFile();;
    switch(string){
    case "A":
    case "B":
        break;
    }
```

Comment: still the same problem...altought like it did before reads the right String,

Comment: Do you want to copy the exact String output and post it here? just before the switch case